# Return multiple values from a function in COM Interfaces

Tags: c++, com, return-value, idl

I did a research and implemented a wrapper function for `GetWindowRect` API, and it works fine. But it can currently only return window coordinates via a `SAFEARRAY`. But I am thinking about how can I also return its actual return value.

I declared it like this:

```
[id(10)] HRESULT WinAPI_GetWindowRect([in] VARIANT hWnd, [out, retval] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) *lpRect);

STDMETHOD(WinAPI_GetWindowRect)(VARIANT hWnd, SAFEARRAY **lpRect);
```

And implementation:

```
STDMETHODIMP CWinAPI::WinAPI_GetWindowRect(VARIANT hWnd, SAFEARRAY **lpRect {

    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> CCSA_RECT;
    RECT Rect;
    HRESULT HResult;

    if (!lpRect) { return E_INVALIDARG; }

    *lpRect = nullptr;

    int Result = (int)GetWindowRect(VariantToHWND(hWnd), &Rect);
    //   ^ I ALSO WANT TO RETURN THIS RESULT TOO

    if (Result != 0)
    {
        HResult = CCSA_RECT.Create(4, 0);
        assert(HResult == S_OK);

        CCSA_RECT[0] = Rect.left;
        CCSA_RECT[1] = Rect.top;
        ...
    }
    else
    { ... }
}
```

But, as I already know, there cannot be multiple `[out, retval]` values, so any suggestions on how to return this value (`Result`) are highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

When I try to return it like this:

```
[id(10)] HRESULT WinAPI_GetWindowRect([in] VARIANT hWnd, [out] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) *lpRect, [out, retval] VARIANT *Result);

STDMETHOD(WinAPI_GetWindowRect)(VARIANT hWnd, SAFEARRAY **lpRect, VARIANT *Result);
```

Assigning it like:

```
Result->intVal = (int)GetWindowRect(VariantToHWND(hWnd), &Rect);
```

I am getting a `Type mismatch` error in below VBScript line when try to use it:

```
Dim lpRect, Result: Result = WINAPI.WinAPI_GetWindowRect(AutoItX3.WinGetHandle("[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]"), lpRect)
```

I want this `SAFEARRAY` to be `[out]` parameter and `Result` to be return value.

Comment: There can, however, be multiple `[out]` and/or `[in, out]` parameters. Having said that, COM convention for reporting success indicator or error code is the `HRESULT` return value that pretty much every COM method has. See also [`HRESULT_FROM_WIN32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680746.aspx)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But I want this value to be returned alone, rather than returning as one of the array's items, so it can be caught from scripting language itself.

Comment: And? What's stopping you?

Comment: Try with `[in, out]`. At least in VBA, `[out]` alone is not supported.

Comment: @AlexandreC. still getting `Type mismatch.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem to a some extent by using a `VARIANT` as `[out]` parameter like this:

```
[id(10)] HRESULT WinAPI_GetWindowRect([in] VARIANT hWnd, [out] VARIANT *Result, [out, retval] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) *lpRect);

STDMETHOD(WinAPI_GetWindowRect)(VARIANT hWnd, VARIANT *Result, SAFEARRAY **lpRect);
```

New implementation:

```
STDMETHODIMP CWinAPI::WinAPI_GetWindowRect(VARIANT hWnd, VARIANT *Result, SAFEARRAY **lpRect) {

    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> CCSA_RECT;
    RECT Rect;
    HRESULT HResult;

    if (!lpRect) { return E_INVALIDARG; }

    *lpRect = nullptr;

    VariantInit(Result);
    Result->vt = VT_I2;

    Result->intVal = (int)GetWindowRect(VariantToHWND(hWnd), &Rect);

    if (Result->intVal != 0)
    {...}
    else
    {...}

}
```

This has been tested using the following VBScript:

```
Dim AutoItX3: Set AutoItX3 = WScript.CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
Dim WINAPI: Set WINAPI = WScript.CreateObject("WinAPIWrapperLib.WINAPI")

Dim lpRect, Result: lpRect = WINAPI.WinAPI_GetWindowRect(AutoItX3.WinGetHandle("[CLASS:ConsoleWindowClass]"), Result)

WScript.Echo "GetWindowRect returned: " + CStr(Result)

If CInt(Result) <> 0 Then
    For iNum = 0 To UBound(lpRect)
        WScript.Echo CStr(lpRect(iNum))
    Next
End If

WScript.Echo(CStr(WINAPI.WinAPI_GetLastErrorMessage))
```

But, I still cannot use `SAFEARRAY` as an `[out]` only parameter, using it as `[out]` only parameter and using `Result` as `[out, retval]` member in following way:

```
[id(10)] HRESULT WinAPI_GetWindowRect([in] VARIANT hWnd, [out] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) *lpRect, [out, retval] VARIANT *Result);
```

still causes the `Type mismatch` error.

Comment: In order for VBS to correctly identify the SafeArray, you'll need to place it inside a Variant. Change your idl as follows: `[id(10)] HRESULT WinAPI_GetWindowRect([in] VARIANT hWnd, [in, out] VARIANT* lpRect, [out, retval] VARIANT* Result);` and adjust your implementation accordingly.